# Rails - Display menu when its main category is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a navbar where I display the **MainCategory** (Men, Women,  Neutral)
(**MainCategory** is a model that have only one attribute `:gender`.)

I've definied the different genders like so:

`enum gender: [:men, :women, :neutral]`in my model.

**Expected:** 
When I hover  the link "Men" I want that the sub menu of "Men" shows up , same for "Women" and "Neutral".

**Category** is another model which has attributes `:gender` and a `:title`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <% MainCategory.order('gender ASC').all.each do |main_cat| %>
            <li class="nav-link gender"><%= main_cat.gender %> 
              <div id="categories">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                   <% Category.where(gender: main_cat.gender).order('title ASC').each do |cat| %>
                     <% if cat.product_with_stock %>
                        <li class="nav-link"><%= link_to  "#{cat.title} ", clients_category_path(cat), class: "nav-link" %></li>  
                     <% end %>
                   <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

This the js file that show and hide the `#category` div.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $(".gender").mouseenter(function(){
      $("#categories").slideDown();
    })

    $("body").click(function() {
      $("#categories").slideUp();
    });

    $("#categories").click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

With this code, I see the same submenu if I hover men  or women, or neutral...

How should I improve this to have what  expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the related gender for each div and open it from your JS:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <% MainCategory.order('gender ASC').all.each do |main_cat| %>
            <li class="nav-link gender" data-gender="<%= main_cat.gender %>"><%= main_cat.gender %> 
              <div class="categories" data-gender="<%= main_cat.gender %>">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                   <% Category.where(gender: main_cat.gender).order('title ASC').each do |cat| %>
                     <% if cat.product_with_stock %>
                        <li class="nav-link"><%= link_to  "#{cat.title} ", clients_category_path(cat), class: "nav-link" %></li>  
                     <% end %>
                   <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(".gender").mouseenter(function(){
    var gender = $(this).data("gender")
    $(".categories[data-gender=" + gender + "]").slideDown();
  })

  $("body").click(function() {
    $(".categories").each(function() { $(this).slideUp() })
  });

  $(".categories").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

**I can't test it, but this should work**

Comment: Super ! this working well I just changed ` $("#categories[data-gender=" + gender + "]").slideDown();`to ` $(".categories[data-gender=" + gender + "]").slideDown();`

Comment: @johan Yup, my bad; didn't notice it ! Glad it helped :-)